# Cursor (SQL) - break the connection after deployment of website to remote server

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, uwsgi

after deployment my webiste (Django + NGINX + uwsgi) I have problem with SQL connections. When I run wscgi for first time, after quit earlier instance, the site loads properly via web-browser (SQL connection is estabilished, and query are executed, I get a result). After go to next site (next query should be executed), I receiving errors like below:

```
[pid: 26143|app: 0|req: 1/1] 2001:470:70:f5f::2 () {58 vars in 1057 bytes} [Sun May 13 19:03:54 2018] GET /index/ => generated 270 bytes in 712 msecs (HTTP/1.0 200) 4 headers in 123 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 26143|app: 0|req: 2/2] 2001:470:70:f5f::2 () {56 vars in 1044 bytes} [Sun May 13 19:04:07 2018] GET /accounts/login/ => generated 634 bytes in 41 msecs (HTTP/1.0 200) 7 headers in 380 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 26143|app: 0|req: 3/3] 2001:470:70:f5f::2 () {60 vars in 1170 bytes} [Sun May 13 19:04:17 2018] POST /accounts/login/ => generated 0 bytes in 2570 msecs (HTTP/1.0 302) 9 headers in 531 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
Internal Server Error: /index/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Env/pyrat/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.InterfaceError: cursor already closed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Env/pyrat/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/root/Env/pyrat/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/root/Env/pyrat/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/root/Env/pyrat/pyrat_server/views.py", line 28, in index
    dbquery.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
  File "/root/Env/pyrat/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/root/Env/pyrat/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/root/Env/pyrat/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/Env/pyrat/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/root/Env/pyrat/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: cursor already closed
[pid: 26143|app: 0|req: 4/4] 2001:470:70:f5f::2 () {56 vars in 1079 bytes} [Sun May 13 19:04:20 2018] GET /index/ => generated 27 bytes in 784 msecs (HTTP/1.0 500) 4 headers in 126 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

The database is on elephantSQL (Postgres). When I tried app on localhost - there was no problems. Does anyone had those type of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone have similar problem - on my localhost one connection to database is enough (at the beginning). After this I can make every query, and there is no problem with connection. Unfortunatelly, on remote host (server) every time before query, the fresh connection to database should be established. Below is the code, which I use:

```
def db_fetchall(query):
    try:
        dbquery = connection.cursor()
        dbquery.execute(query)
    except InterfaceError:
        dbquery.close()
        dbquery = connection.cursor()
        dbquery.execute(query)
    return dbquery.fetchall()
```